# Modular arithmetics

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've been reading about some examples concerning DSS/DSA signature security and there is one part of an example that I do not understand the maths. Namely, how do you calculate this:

$w = (s^{-1}$ $mod$ $q)$ 
In this example let's say $q = 13$ and $s = 10$.

So we have
$w = (10^{-1}$ $mod$ $13) = 4$

How do we get 4 as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $q$ and $s$ are relatively prime, using e.g. the Euclidean algorithm, you can find intergers $x,y$ such that 
$$qx+sy=1.$$
Therefore, if you look at this equality modulo $q$, you see that
$$sy\equiv 1\pmod q.$$
This integer $y$ is the "inverse" of $s$ modulo $q$.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle 10\cdot4=40\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$\displaystyle 10^{-1}\equiv4\pmod{13}$ dividing either sides by $10$ as $(10,13)=1$

Comment: Using http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma, such inverse of $a\pmod m$ always exists iff $(a,b)=1$

Answer (score 1):

While with these small numbers it is possible to just guess-and-check an inverse, generally you use the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure). It goes like this: since $10$ and $13$ are relatively prime, there is a way to find integers $a$ and $b$ so that $$10a+13b=1$$ If you do this, then reducing that equation modulo $13$, you have $$10a\equiv 1$$ and $a$ is the inverse of $10$ mod $13$. So your task is to find that $a$. The algorithm linked above lets you find an $a$ (and a $b$) after several iterations, essentially replacing the pair $(10,13)$ with smaller and smaller pairs until $a$ and $b$ are apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Inverses modulo small integers are usually quickly computable by fraction fiddling. For example

$\rm\ mod\ 13\!:\, \ \begin{eqnarray}1\,\equiv&& -12\\ 10\,\equiv&& -3\end{eqnarray}\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ \dfrac{1}{10}\,\equiv\, \dfrac{-12}{-3}\,\equiv\, 4,\ $ indeed $\,\ 4\cdot 10 = 3\cdot 13 + 1\equiv 1\pmod{13}$

For larger moduli one may use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242). Given integers $\rm\,x,y\,$ it yields integers $\rm\,a,b\,$ such that $\rm\, ax+by = gcd(x,y)\ $ ([Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity)). Thus, when the gcd $=1,\,$

$$\ \rm ax+by = 1\ \Rightarrow\ ax\equiv 1\!\!\pmod y$$

yielding the inverse of $\rm\,x,\,$ modulo $\rm\,y,\,$ i.e. $\,
 \rm x^{-1} = 1/x\, \equiv\, a\pmod y$

**Beware** $\ $ The use of fractions in modular arithmetic is valid only when the denominator is invertible. Otherwise the quotient need not be unique, e.g. mod $\rm\:10,\:$ $\rm\:4\,x\equiv 2\:$ has solutions $\rm\:x\equiv 3,8,\:$ so the "fraction" $\rm\:x \equiv 2/4\pmod{10}\,$ cannot designate a unique solution of $\,4x\equiv 2.\,$ Indeed, the solution is $\rm\:x\equiv 1/2\equiv 3\pmod 5,\,$ which requires canceling $\,2\,$ from the *modulus* too, since $\rm\:10\:|\:4x-2\iff5\:|\:2x-1.\:$

Generally the grade-school rules of fraction arithmetic apply *universally* (i.e. in all rings) where the denominators are invertible. This fundamental property will be clarified conceptually when one learns in university algebra about the *universal properties* of fractions rings and localizations.